# Guava vs Google Play Services: Build Conflict

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services, guava

I would like to use Guava and GooglePlayServices in the same project. After I  added Guava via gradle, I got a dex build error. I was able to isolate the conflicting culprit as GooglePlayServices. I can build using one, or the other, not both.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'}
```

Anyone else encounter this? Solution appreciated.

Comment: I tried the `dependcecies` you provide, and can get gradle build finished successfully. What's the problem, can you provide the logcat?

Comment: The only feedback is a dex compile error from gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've encountered the 65k method limit issue.

The easiest fix is instead of including the whole google play service library, you only include those you need.
See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

For more information regarding 65k issue:
see 
https://www.contentful.com/blog/2014/10/30/android-and-the-dex-64k-methods-limit/